# javascript sort obj changing id #'s

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to sort my hash table pull down menu alphabetically... using this function:

```
function getSortedKeys(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for(var key in obj) {
        keys.push(obj[key]);
        keys[keys.length-1]['key'] = key;
    }
    return keys.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0;
    });           
}
```

This sorts the pull down menu...although it changes the original id# of my menu items which screws some things up on my site... is it possible to keep the original id# of each menu item and still sort?

sorry..here's the hash code:

```
var clientProjectsHash = {};
clientProjectsHash['1'] = {};
clientProjectsHash['1']['name'] = 'RONA';
clientProjectsHash['2'] = {};
clientProjectsHash['2']['name'] = 'CMS';
clientProjectsHash['3'] = {};
clientProjectsHash['3']['name'] = 'ALT';
```

and getSortedKeys is called by:

```
function getInitialClient() {
    clientProjectsHash = getSortedKeys(clientProjectsHash);
        for (clientKey in clientProjectsHash) {
            if(clientKey > 0) {
                return clientKey;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This shouldn't change IDs, is there more to the code? Are the IDs generated dynamically?

Comment: The only thing where you are changing something is in this line: `keys[keys.length-1]['key'] = key;`. Does this have anything to do with "ID"? If not, please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: What "id" are you talking about?  What does `obj` look like?  When you sort an array, the values may wind up with new keys (since they may be in new spots).

Comment: yes each menu item is in a hash table like so: hashtable[id#][menu-name]... hash[1]['example1'] ... hash[2]['example2']...etc

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is.  `getSortedKeys(clientProjectsHash)` returns me an array sorted just fine and with the correct keys.  I do see that you are overwriting `clientProjectsHash`.  Also, you are using `for..in` for an array, don't do that.

Comment: its not changing hash "ALT" to id=0 ?? cuz its doing it for me.. and "RONA" id changes to 3

Comment: what is your expected return value from getInitialClient()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are returning an array, and expecting it to be an object.  These are different things in JavaScript.  Nothing is "changing"; your "ids" (or "hashes") are not being modified.

Your `clientProjectsHash` starts as an *object*!  Objects are unordered and can have any string as a key.  When you do `getSortedKeys(clientProjectsHash);` you are being returned an *array*!  Arrays are ordered, and have numeric indexes  (keys) that start at 0.

---

```
clientProjectsHash = getSortedKeys(clientProjectsHash);
for (clientKey in clientProjectsHash) {
}
```

This  ***overwrites*** `clientProjectsHash` with an *array*.  Then you `for..in` over it (you should *not* use `for..in` for arrays, by the way).

The array returned from `getSortedKeys` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'ALT',
        key: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'CMS',
        key: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'RONA',
        key: 1
    }
]
```

So, in your `for..in`, `clientKey` will be `0`, `1`, and `2`.  The indexes of the array.  Your `key` values are *not* changing, you are just reading the wrong value.

Try this instead:

```
function getInitialClient() {
    var clientKeys = getSortedKeys(clientProjectsHash);
    for(var i = 0, len = clientKeys.length; i < len; i++){
        var clientKey = clientKeys[i];
        if(clientKey.key > 0){
            return clientKey.key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @rubberchicken: What do you mean "the id is null"?  What id?  What are you trying to access?  What are you trying to do?  I still have no idea what your issue is.  Maybe I returned the wrong value from `getInitialClient`, I changed it so it returns the ID, try that?

Comment: it does not sort now.. i added pic to main edit for you to see

Comment: @rubberchicken: How are the values getting into that dropdown?  How does it "not sort", I didn't touch that code?  Can you show more of your code?  Where is the code that calls `getInitialClient`?  Where else is `clientProjectsHash` used?

Comment: I asked for help on this topic before.. link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003844/sorting-my-javascript-pull-down-menu-by-name-not-key

Comment: @rubberchicken: Yes, and your `getSortedKeys` function works fine.  What's the *real* issue here?  I still don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: ok so the menu items in the drop down list all have a unique Key# (id#)...for example CMS = KEY#1  ... RONA = KEY#2 ... BELL = KEY#3 and so on... after it sorts the hash table it changed the KEY value.. so BELL changed to KEY#0 (ID#0) -- then CMS changed to KEY#2(ID#2) and so on... i want to know if theres a way of sorting it where it does NOT change the KEY value and it stays the same as original.. and still sorts by name

Comment: @rubberchicken: How are you trying to get the "KEY" value?

Comment: don't worry about it...i never liked using javascript to begin with.. i'll just try to re-write the whole function in another language. thanks for your time and help.